# Shared Library of jsp files between

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have multiple projects that use the same framework. To share `java` code between them is easy, but how do you share `jsp` pages. For example, I have

```
public static enum DialogResponseType {
    ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION, GOOD, SERVER, SUCCESS
}
```

To use the `enum` in my `jsp` I have a `fragmentStatus.jsp`

```
<%@ page
    import="mypackagepath.DialogResponseType"%>
<script>
function clientStatusEnumToResponse(status) {
    switch (status) {
    case '<%=Status.SUCCESS.toString()%>':
        return "label-success";
    case '<%=Status.INFORMATION.toString()%>':
        return "label-info";
....
```

Now I need to use `fragementStatus.jsp` in multiple projects so that I don't have to include it.

When I include it in a common project `Dynamic Web Project`, and release the war, the dependent projects are not able to find the `jsp`.

Is there a way to make a `Dynamic Web Project` that is a library?